# Firebird increment a field value in place on update

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm using Firebird 2.5.9. I have a table of information on a set of hardware impact devices that includes a running counter of the # of times the device has impacted.  Each time a device is "fired", the hardware will impact 1 or more times; upon completion of the firing event, that device's row is updated with the timestamp and a result code, and I need to increment the running counter column with the number of impacts for that fire event.

I can do this as a separate query to get the field's current value, increment it and use that new value in the update statement, but that seems like a lot of extra overhead.  This sort of scenario can't be that uncommon, so I assume that there's some straightforward way to do this within an update statement, but I don't know what it is.  I also realize that I could do this as a stored procedure, but for now I want to just do it in the update statement if possible.

Comment: You would probably be better off with inserting individual events, and summing/counting them, maybe with a regular aggregation job to aggregate multiple older events into a single aggregated event. Modifying a record repeatedly when events occur usually incurs overhead due to extra record versions/garbage collection, and could be a bottleneck for processing events because instead of just inserting, you'd need to read, lock and update a record.

Comment: Mark - I'm trying to avoid a long-running log table, because this software has to run on very lightweight hardware (industrial panel-mount PCs with very limited storage) and there usually are hundreds of impactors in the system (our largest installation has over 900.)  There's a running log, but it only keeps the last 30 days of firing data.  The aggregation job sounds like it may be the way to go - I'll dig into it.

Comment: `because this software has to run on very lightweight hardware` this exactly mean you have to introduce an intermediate aggregating layer between Firebird and hardware events. Firebird is indetermenistic system, where things like garbage collection can be triggered in lucky or unlucky moment causing slow-downs or even pauses. You better make an usual flip-flop buffer in 2 or more FIFO plain files, and make your application synchronously dump hardware events into "most recent" file and another app to asynchronously dump "least recent" file into the database

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for now by expanding the existing before-insert trigger to a before-insert-or-update trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TBIU_RPRS1 FOR RPRS ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
  IF (INSERTING AND NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN NEW.ID = NEXT VALUE FOR SEQ_GLOBAL;
  IF (UPDATING) THEN NEW.STRIKES = OLD.STRIKES + NEW.STRIKES;
END;
```

Comment: Make sure you document this explicitly, because it can lead to confusion (e.g. someone wanting to 'correct' a value). It might be better to do this explicitly in the update statement itself.

Answer (score 0):

Running counters, sums, etc used to be called "stored aggregates". They are usually maintained by triggers on events tables. But before using them make sure that a simple view with plain count() is not fast enough for you.

Comment: Not sure a trigger will handle this situation - the counter will be incremented a variable number of times on a successful firing event, and not at all on a failed event.  But I'll look at that.

Comment: when i was doing a thing like that, triggers were clearing out (NULLing) those aggregates, and before actually reading there was a call to SP that re-calculated missing aggregates. Granted, in that case "update" and "read" accesses almost never co-existed, it was either one phase or another. Basically that meant most updating events except very first just soon had to clear the already cleared "branches" up the tree, so they no more actually changed the data rows.

Comment: I've implemented this aggregation in the before-insert trigger (which already existed to sequence the ID) for now.  We'll see how it runs under pressure, and if necessary, I'll split the process as you recommended above.  Thanks.

Comment: Hope it works @SteveS - just think most practical systems have an explicit operation of cache invalidation, purposedly distinct from re-warming re-populating updating the cache. Even Windows GDI :-)